# Trying to open 127: local host in vscode it is not opening instead something else like this is opening

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

Basically I am just doing testing a CRUD API down below and whenever I open the vscode live server this is displaying on the screen -

[Error Page opening or example page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0sec.png)

After clicking on more I get to this website

[Local Host error and connection problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FftZz.png)

Now what should I do?

- I tried to do a lot of things like -
- Editing DNS Settings
- Securing several connections etc.

But none of it worked! What should I do now?